# Openlayers 3 Vector Layer error

Tags: vector, layers, openlayers

Getting error from Firebug on running this code:

> TypeError: f is null  (ol.js 409)

The map is showing up properly. After adding the line : `this.map.addLayer(vectorLayer);` I get the mentioned error. :-(

```
var projection_lan = 'EPSG:4326';
var projection_lat = 'EPSG:3857';
var marker_icon = 'resources/img/green_marker.png';
var map = null;

var pos = ol.proj.transform([ 12.102727890014648, 49.017269896565764 ],projection_lan, projection_lat);

function init() {

    var localTiles = new ol.layer.Tile({
        source : new ol.source.XYZ({
            url : this.tiles_url
        })
    });

    this.map = new ol.Map({
        layers : [ new ol.layer.Tile({
            source : new ol.source.MapQuest({
                layer : 'sat'
            })
        }) ],
        target : 'map',
        view : new ol.View({
            center : pos,
            zoom : 10
        })
    });

    var iconFeature = new ol.Feature(
        {geometry : new ol.geom.Point(pos)
    });

    var iconStyle = new ol.style.Style({
        image : new ol.style.Icon({
            src : 'http://ol3js.org/en/master/examples/data/icon.png'
        })
    });

    iconFeature.setStyle(iconStyle);

    var vectorSource = new ol.source.Vector({
        features : [ iconFeature ]
    });

    var vectorLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
        source : vectorSource
    });

    this.map.addLayer(vectorLayer);
}
```

Comment: It works with this demo using your code http://bl.ocks.org/ThomasG77/16bfcdab4671c7e8a300 So, how do you call init() and how your HTML look?

Comment: Your Example works fine :-) Found now the problem. I called the map from an xhtml-File. I don't really know what was going wrong with an normal xhtml File...but after desperatly changing to an simple html File everything seems to be fine. Thaks a lot !!!!

Comment: You can repost as an answer, so I can mark the problem as solved :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works with this demo using [your code](http://bl.ocks.org/ThomasG77/16bfcdab4671c7e8a300)

So, how do you call init() and how your HTML look?

Comment: Your Example works fine :-) Found now the problem. I called the map from an xhtml-File. I don't really know what was going wrong with an normal xhtml File...but after desperatly changing to an simple html File everything seems to be fine. Thaks a lot !!!!

Answer (score 0):

Your longitude and latitude on your icon is reversed in comparison to your view.. Also you'll probably have to use

```
ol.proj.transform(Longitude, Latitude fromProjection, toProjection)
```

on the icon as well. (Not sure what your projection_lan and projection_lat is)

Comment: Added the projections and transformed the projection of the icon as well(@see first post)...still getting the same error :-(